# Conversion of N:M relationship to database schema

Tags: database-design, erd

Suppose that you want to convert a relationship of the following form:

```
Entity1 (N,0) ------ (1,M) Entity2
```

Or in crow's foot notation:

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwK9B.png)

The standard schema conversion is:

```
Entity1 (**Entity1No**, ....)

Entity2 (**Entity2No**, ...)

Entity1_Entity2 (***Entity1No***, ***Entity2No***, ....)
 FOREIGN KEY (Entity1No) REFERENCES (Entity1)
 FOREIGN KEY (Entity2No) REFERENCES (Entity2)
```

(Here boldface means primary key and italics foreign key).

However I do not see how to implement the fact that, according to the relationship cardinality, there must be at least one Entity2 related to Entity1. Is there a way to include this requirement in the database schema?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot specify that there is at least one entity that is related on the many - side of a relation. At least as far as I'm aware of.

You could implement a CHECK constraint, but I wouldn't do it for several reasons (performance / maintainability). You could use triggers / stored procedures to make sure that you always have at least one. It depends on the general software design if this is appropriate or not.

Usually, you have some business layer in whatever programming language which makes sure that the data is consistent. It cares about the more complex cases, which needs business knowledge. Database constraints (like NOT NULL) are rather trivial and cannot express real business consistency. They only check for the most essential and most basic consistency. Your case seems to be basic as well, but it's already out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is easy to forget that ERDs are meant to capture business requirements, from which database requirements are only a subset. Best Regards.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you think that the answer is complete and helpful enough. (You can only accept one if there are multiple, as the "correct answer" or the one that helped you the most.)

Comment: Exactly!  And this flows from two confusions that are endemic to today's database architects.  The first is the confusion between the ER model and the relational model.  The second is the confusion between analysis and design.  You analyze the business, and you design the database (and the applications).